# Why doesn't the deleted table in a FOR/AFTER DELETE Trigger contain data of the Deleted Record?

Tags: t-sql, triggers, auditing

Given the following audit table:

```
CREATE TABLE Auditing.[Record Deletion Times]
(
    ID BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Schema] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [Table] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [Record ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date-Time] DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    [Record Information] NVARCHAR(1024) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [Record Deleted Times Primary Key] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        ID ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [Record Deleted Modified Times Unique Key] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [Schema] ASC,
        [Table] ASC,
        [Record ID] ASC,
        [Date-Time] ASC
    )
)
```

and the following data table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Key] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
)
```

I want a trigger that will record information to `Record Deletion Times` when it is deleted from `Items`.  I have found that I am able to do this with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger (whereby I record the data then manually delete the record in the trigger) but was wondering why a `FOR` or `AFTER` trigger does not do the same thing without the need for me performing the deletion myself.  My guess is that `deleted` doesn't contain any data about the record that was deleted once it was deleted (what's the best way to debug a trigger?).

This is the trigger I hoped to use which failed to record anything in `Record Deletion Times`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Items Deleted]
    ON Items
FOR DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO Auditing.[Record Deletion Times]
    SELECT
        'dbo',
        'Items',
        deleted.ID,
        GETUTCDATE(),
        CONCAT
        (
            'Key: ''',
            Items.Key,
            ''' Value: ''',
            Items.Value,
            ''''
        )
    FROM Items
    JOIN deleted ON deleted.ID = Items.ID
```

This is the trigger I ended-up using instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Items Deleted]
    ON Items
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Auditing.[Record Deletion Times]
    SELECT
        'dbo',
        'Items',
        deleted.ID,
        GETUTCDATE(),
        CONCAT
        (
            'Key: ''',
            Items.Key,
            ''' Value: ''',
            Items.Value,
            ''''
        )
    FROM Items
    JOIN deleted ON deleted.ID = Items.ID

    DELETE Items
    FROM Items
    JOIN deleted ON deleted.ID = Items.ID
END
```

Comment: Oh - I see why that didn't work now!  I'm reading back from the table in its new state!  I was joining to it as a safety precaution (I've done the same thing for some UPDATE and INSERT triggers) as I have previously just used those tables directly to modify the table in question and they updated everything in the target table!  It's another problem though so I'll raise a separate question for it if needed.

Comment: You might also look at Temporal Tables, if you haven't already, as this provides automatic auditing of updates and deletes out-of-the-box.

Comment: Do you know whether this is possible without Azure?  I've had a quick search for Temporal Tables and everything seems to suggest to use an Azure SQL Server Managed Instance.

Comment: System versioning is part of the ANSI SQL Standard, all supported versions of SQL Server implement it, although I haven't used Single azure database instances which do have limitations - although [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables) suggests you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be selecting *from* your `Items` table since the row(s) you want are now deleted.

Just select *from* `Deleted`

Ie

```
INSERT INTO RecordDeletionTimes
    SELECT
        'dbo',
        'Items',
        ID,
        GETUTCDATE(),
        CONCAT
        (
            'Key: ''',
            [Key],
            ''' Value: ''',
            Value,
            ''''
        )
    FROM deleted ;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=576d86d483ca28dcc868c8a807fcc253)

The best way to debug your trigger is to just `select * from deleted` and test in SSMS using a begin tran/rollback.